# How to remove old expandable foam weatherseal

Tags: doors, sealing, door-frame

How does one remove old expandable foam weatherseal from a wooden doorframe?

I’ve bought some new stuff, but I don’t know how to go about removing the old from the doorframe.

[image: EXPANDABLE FOAM WEATHERSEAL]

Comment: The classic method involving elbow grease, patience and a scraper or razor.

Comment: @SolarMike What kinda scrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a wood door frame, you probably don't want to scrape too aggressively, or you'll end up gouging the wood. I like to use plastic razor blades for things like that.

[image: razors]

They are color coded based on hardness. Orange is the softest / most flexible, then blue, then yellow. The yellow ones are almost completely in-flexible, and the orange are quite soft. I would go with the blue. Black is a different kind of plastic and I have never used them.

At any rate, these are very cheap and worth keeping around. They fit into a normal scraper:
[image]

If you cant quite get all the old gunk off, you might want to try scraping off as much as you can and then using some acetone to soften what is left. Just make sure it won't damage any finishing that is on the wood.